# Binary Function on an unordered pair?

Tags: functions, binary-operations

We define binary functions such as addition over the reals can be defined like this in the various notations,
$+(a,b)=a+b=b+a=+(b,a)$ in this case there is a separate mapping as for the tuples $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ for $a,b$ in $R$, can we define the addition function so that it acts on an unordered pair and therefore has one mapping for the sum of $a$ and $b$, and therefore for the unordered pair $[a,b]$?

Comment: The answer is: yes, we can. And, the other way round - any map of unordered pairs to the set gives rise to a *commutative* binary operation on that set.

Comment: How would that look or be defined, because typical function notation implies that $f(a,b)$ and $f(b,a)$ are their own mappings?

Comment: Well, define the function on ordered pairs using the function on unordered pairs as such: $f(a,b)\overset{\text{def}}{=}\mathfrak{f}([a,b])$ where $\mathfrak{f}$ is the function on unordered pairs. Because $[a,b]=[b,a]$ you automatically have that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)$.